# Is there a way to write in the data of one cell from another cell via a function?

Tags: google-sheets

For example, say I have some data in A1, and I want to write it in C1, is there a function I could use that does this?

I know you can write in via cell C1 "=A1" which would obtain the result of A1, however, I want cell C1 to maintain the value of A1 even if the cell in C1 is moved, for e.g to D1.

Answer (score 2):

If we drag-and-drop **C1** to another position, its formula will remain unchanged: `=A1`.

If we copy or cut **C1** and paste it to **D1**, then `A1` will be automatically adjusted to `B1`, because it's a relative reference. To avoid this use an absolute reference `=$A$1`.

If we want to keep **C1** in place but copy its formula while keeping the reference unchanged, apply the same, use an absolute reference, in this case `=$A$1`.

Comment: Ok cool, but I want the value in a cell to stay in the same location when moving that cell.

Comment: @JimJam : What do you mean by "moving"? drag-and-drop, copy, cut, ...?